# ¿Cómo establecer la hoja activa por nombre en PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy utilizando PHPExcel, para rescatar datos de la bbdd e insertarlos en el archivo excel.

Pero me encuentro con un problema, y es que el archivo excel tiene diferentes hojas, sé que se puede hacer mediante

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1))
```

Pero si lo hago así y luego se cambian las hojas de orden, lo va a seguir haciendo pero en las hojas equivocadas.

Por este motivo quiero saber si puedo rescatar una hoja del excel (mediante el nombre de dicha hoja), insertarle los datos, y guardar el archivo con todas sus hojas.
He visto que hay un método

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
```

Pero esto te rescata la hoja, le insertas datos, y al guardarlo se te guarda el archivo solo con esa hoja. Las demás se las carga.

Comment: TaGy, bienvenid@ a SOes. No me queda muy clara tu pregunta. Estas recuperando informacion de la bd, y despues usas phpexcel para crear una archivo de para abrir en Excel. A que te refieres con "rescatar una hoja del excel"? te refieres a que quieres insertar la información de la bd en esa hoja especifica?

Comment: @Kenny si no entiendo mal esta buscando ubicar una hoja por nombre y no por indice.. por si se las mueven.

Comment: Buenas, si recupero información de la bd, utilizo phpexcel, para manipular un archivo excel (que ya existe) y más en concreto para manipular una hoja de ese archivo excel.
 Acabo de encontrar la respuesta aqui: http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel.html

Tengo que utilizar el metodo $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheetname);

Y por lo que veo funciona bien.

Un saludo y perdón por las molestias.

Comment: @gbianchi, aaa... ya entendi. TaGy creo que en vez de index se puede seleccionar por nombre. Te dejo una respuesta, ojala te sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `PhpExcel` puedes seleccionar la hoja activa de dos posibles formas. Antes de intentar cualquiera de las dos formas, recuerda que tu archivo debe tener por lo menos dos hojas, de lo contrario recibiras un error.

La primera forma es por el index, la cual obviamente ya sabes

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
```

La segunda forma es obtener la hoja activa por nombre

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('MiHojaDeExcel');
```

---

Puedes tener más informacion en esta [pregunta del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271943/how-to-set-active-sheet-without-loading-an-xlsx-file/18272456#18272456).

Comment: Exacto, aunque ya lo había visto antes, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @TaGy de nada. Si me permites voy a modificar un poquito el titulo para que otras personas puedan beneficiarse de tu pregunta, que me parece buena.

Comment: Por supuesto! Gracias